# Pass parameters while routing dynamically in React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Required Scenario

I have 4 pages Registration form, If we close the window without completing the Registration, then we have to auto drive the page while loading.We are saving the data in local storage but we want send the data object to the Dynamic Routing Page in the application. can we have chance to add the parameters while Routing.

If I am in the wrong direction please suggest me the proper way.

Comment: do you want to pass props with dynamic routing or normally to link or to Route can you clarify a little

Comment: For Dynamic Routing

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-parameters-with-history-push-in-react-router-v4/45263164#45263164

Comment: for static routing check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255415/passing-props-to-component-in-react-router-v4/44255850#44255850 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689680/use-url-on-a-component-page-to-identify-and-pass-data-in-state-from-parent-with/46733186#46733186